The "await" keyword is only allowed in an asynchronous function
when I trying to  await my "async def" I get the error: "The "await" keyword is only allowed in an asynchronous function". My code:
import time
import asyncio
energy = 0
async def regen_energy(energy):
    while energy != 1000:
        energy += 1
        await time.sleep(0.5)
        await print(energy)
await regen_energy(energy)

What's or Where's my mistake?

but when i trying without await i get this error: coroutine 'regen_energy' was never awaited

Here is fixed version:

Use asyncio.sleep() instead synchronous time.sleep()
Why use await with the print() function? That doesn't make sense
Use asyncio.run()

import asyncio


async def regen_energy(energy):
    while energy != 10:
        energy += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)  # <-- use asyncio.sleep() instead
        print(energy)  # <-- remove await here


energy = 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(regen_energy(energy))

